# When I render different routes except main page, html is not loading the sources,express-handlebars-Node.js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

[image]I am using express-handlebars in my Node.js project.
I properly set up express-handlebars.Main page is loading successfully, there is no error however when I render other routes html is not loading css and js:

http://localhost:4000/user/signup (I only have plain form)

```
 http://localhost:4000/user/stylesheets/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
    GET http://localhost:4000/user/images/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
    GET http://localhost:4000/user/javascripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
    GET http://localhost:4000/user/javascripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
    GET http://localhost:4000/user/javascripts/all.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

express-handlebars set up

```
//layout.hbs:
<head>
  <title>{{title}}</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css' type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  {{> navbar}} //partial
  {{{body}}}
  <script src="javascripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="javascripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="javascripts/all.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
//user.js
router.get("/user/signup", (req, res) => {
  res.render("user/signup", { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
});
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there can you please share your directory like which folder contain which file.I think problem is this line.if your style.css is in any folder.You should mention it like this

for example if my style.css file is in public/css/style.css i would writ like this

`<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css' type="text/css" />`

Not like this

`<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' type="text/css" />`

I hope it will work.Thanks

Comment: Brother it worked. I knew that i made very stupid mistake.  Thank you so much

Comment: But i wonder why the main page was loading. it uses same code